# Issue with getLastRow(), output includes the empty rows as well which I do not want

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

getLastRow() not working in my script. I am trying to return the last row that has data. But since the spreadsheet has empty rows below the rows filled with data, the script returns with all the rows but I want it to stop on the last row that has the data. Can someone tell me how to fix this? The data contains the array formula and here is the script:-

```
function Productivity() 
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Do you want to send emails to all PRICE ACCURACY resources now?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Process the user's response.
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) 
  {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Productivity Report Out')
    var range = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
    var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
    //Logger.log(range.length)
    for(var i=1;i<=lastrow; i++) //i<range.length

    {
      Logger.log("Index:"+i+" | ["+range[i]+"]")
      var status =  range[i][14]
      if(status !='No')
      {
        var name =  range[i][0]
        var ldap = range[i][1]
        var target = range[i][2]
        var new_mvt = range[i][3]
        var onboarding = range[i][4]
        var ubio_rates =  range[i][5]
        var violation = range[i][6]
        var reevaluation = range[i][7]
        var total = range[i][8]
        var current_productivity = range[i][9]
        var deficit = range[i][10]
        var remaining_checks = range[i][11]
        var week = range[i][12]
        var date = range[i][13]
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `lastRow` but don't use it.

I'm guessing this is what you're looking for:

```
for(var i=1; i<=lastRow; i++)
```

As designed, `.getLastRow()` returns the last row that has data. Or from documentation: `Returns the position of the last row that has content.`

- [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Side note: You're beginning your loop at index 1 (row 2), if you do not have a header row, you should use 0 (row 1).

Comment: But when modifying this "for(var i=1; i<=lastRow; i++)"

receiving this error - ReferenceError: lastrow is not defined

Comment: `ReferenceError: lastrow is not defined`, it's `lastRow` not `lastrow`

Comment: Please also help me with this error - 

Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property '14' of undefined
Productivity @ Test Script.gs:17

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your sheet? Additionally, you can add `Logger.log("Index:"+i+" | ["+range[i]+"]")` above your `var status = range[i][14]` line to see what is being looped over.

Comment: Is there a possible way to connect and solve this real time. I would really appreciate it if you can.

Comment: updated the code I am running, please see as the last row is still not working.

How can I add the screenshot of the sheet? please let me know!

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: I thought the error is till the line 36 hence provided that much of the code. Is the entire code needed?

Comment: NEWAZA, please read the updated code and let me know what can we do to fix the issue?

Comment: Add a link to your sheet in the post temporarily and I will look at it

Answer (score 0):

#### Getting blank rows in your data

`if(status !='No')` would be true for a blank line.  Perhaps you are using something like an Array Formula that is causing the getLastRow() calculation to be incorrect.  Do a Logger.log(lastRow) and see if it makes sense.

Try this function:

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
  //const h = Utilities.formatString('col: %s len: %s', col, rcA.length - s);
  //Logger.log(h);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(h).setWidth(150).setHeight(100), 'Col Length')
}
```

Comment: Yes Cooper, the data in the sheet has the Array formula.

Also tried using the logger.log(lastrow) but it returned the total rows including empty rows.

Please help!

Comment: I'd recommend stop using the array formula and replace it with a script.  But I'm sure that others would disagree but I don't care that's what I'd do anyway.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make get lastrow work with array formula?

Comment: Try using the getColumnHeight function it might work.

Comment: Thanks Cooper, since I am new to this and don't really know the coding. Can you also let me know where shall I place your provided function in my above script???